# How can I fix repeating visual artifacts of my cursor/caret shape in VS Code's integrated terminal?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I just installed Visual Studio Code and I'm facing a problem while writing on terminal.
When I'm writing commands, some white rectangles start to appear as you can see in the images bellow.

[image]

[image]

If I change the window to another program and then back to VS Code, these rectangles disappear, but as soon I start to write, they appear again.

Does someone know how can I get rid of these rectangles while writing on terminal?

Version info:
MacOS High Sierra v10.13.6;
VSC v1.80.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll wager a guess. From your screenshot, I'm guessing your cursor is the block cursor (`"terminal.integrated.cursorStyle": "block"`). I'm guessing this is a rendering bug, in which case I'd suggest to fiddle with the `terminal.integrated.gpuAcceleration` setting and see if any of those values gets rid of the issue for you.

Comment: I turned terminal.integrated.gpuAcceleration to "Off" and it is ok now! Thank you!