# Why does my vscode terminal keep delaying output until i type another character

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal

Whatever I type in a VScode terminal window, it works but after some of the output appears it frequently freezes, sometimes for a few seconds but mostly until I type another keystroke then the rest of the output appears (immediately)

I've tried removing my `.bashrc` file and use basic terminal but it still happens

It happens with both tmux and bash terminals

Regular non-vscode terminals work fine

I am on Ubuntu

Comment: sounds like possibly a case of hardware acceleration problems. see also https://stackoverflow.com/q/76739924/11107541

Answer (score 0):

### Cursor blink

This is certainly a hack and not a fix.

I tried many things but all terminals show this problem no matter what settings I changed.

Finally, out of desperation I found that turning on cursor blinking in vsCode settings (can't remember why it was off, doesn't bother me either way) forces the output to always 'finish' within a 'blink'.

It a weird work-around but after hours of trying to fix this and considering an operation system reinstall, using cursor blink to fix my paused output seems good for me.

[image]